# Connect remotely to Database by SoftEther VPN Client

Tags: vpn, connection, softether

As i have just started studying about Softether VPN, i have some questions :

I want to work at home, and I installed SoftEther Server at my company, and SoftEther Client at home, I successfully connected the two.

My question is: I want to establish a connection to the database (SQL Server) in company which is stored in another PC within the LAN network - Local IP Address is (192.168.10.241\DB) - I used this IP to connect to DB at my company

So, I would like to ask you that is it possible to connect to this database from SQL Server at home with SoftEther VPN Client?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It should work, if you can reach the DB server with it's ip address but there are some points to consider:

- The DB server firewall allows connection from the vpn ip address range that you are using.
- The db user account you are using to connect to, has the required privilage to connect from a any remote host (or from vpn ip range).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so in the Server name field of the SQL Server at my PC at home, I will enter the IP (192.168.10.241\DB) of the DB at my company ? Thanks

Comment: You can try with ip or hostname. Sometime hostname doesn't work if you are not using the office DNS.

Comment: What kind of DB are you using? You can't connect like `192.168.10.241\DB`. For example, for mysql, you connect to certain port:3306. Most of the case you will be connecting also with some client software.